# Can't login to Windows 10 after drive repair: "Your device is offline. Please sign in with the last password used on this device"

Tags: windows-10

One day my computer did drive repair. After that when I can't log in using my password. It shows "Your device is offline. Please sign in with the last password used on this device". I tried to troubleshoot and open in safe mode. I cannot login there either.

Comment: You need the correct password.

Comment: Make sure the keyboard layout is what you expect, so you're actually typing the characters you think you're typing.

Comment: You may have changed your password recently. If so, use the password you had prior to changing it.

Answer (score 0):

This message is present if you are not connected to your domain controller in most cases.

If the PC did a drive repair your cached credentials might have gotten lost or the token expired.

If you have the VPN options for login, launch that first than logon. If not, you will need to be physically in the office that has access via Wifi or LAN to the domain controller

Comment: I tried to make another account by command prompt but could not. Ain't there any other way?